# How to show a popup while a file is getting uploaded when the form is submitted on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using the type 'file' with attribute 'multiple' in 'input' tag to upload multiple files on the webpage. Once I click the submit button, it takes a lot of time to upload the files and till the time all the files are uploaded, the user has to wait for the next web-page.
Following is the syntax I use:

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_submit">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="Label1"><strong>Upload files</strong>
  </label>
   <br>
    <input type="file" id="Label1" name="Label1" multiple">
 </div>
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

What I want add here is a popup when the submit button is pressed which will show which file is getting uploaded at the moment.
How to use javascript to achieve this?

Comment: Where is the javascript that you use? Do you use Javascript for this?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I haven't used any javascript yet for this, don't know what to use here. Can you suggest something?

Comment: Add a JavaScript function that shows a pop up and register it to the on click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I want add here is a popup when the submit button is pressed which will show which file is getting uploaded at the moment.

You are asking a lot. But here a cool and simple example about what can be done to inform the user the upload is processing.

```js
// Submit handler
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

  // Make sure the are files
  let fileCount = this.querySelector("[type='file']").files.length
  if (fileCount) {

    // Toggle the the "Uploading..." message
    document.querySelector("#uploading-msg").classList.toggle("msg-hidden");

    // Disable the button
    this.querySelector("[type='submit']").setAttribute("disabled", true);
  } else {
  
    // Do not submit if there are no files
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})


// Do not use that JS!
// It's just to disable the submit in this demo
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", e => e.preventDefault())
```

```css
#uploading-msg,
#uploading-msg+.dots {
  color: green;
}

.msg-hidden,
.msg-hidden+.dots {
  display: none !important;
}

.dots {
  display: inline-block !important;
  position: absolute;
  animation: 2s infinite animated-dots;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes animated-dots {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 0.7em;
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_submit">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Label1"><strong>Upload files</strong>
  </label>
    <br>
    <input type="file" id="Label1" name="Label1" multiple>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <span id="uploading-msg" class="msg-hidden">Uploading</span>
  <div class="dots">...</div>
</form>
```